# ASP.NET Core Web API - Protect Image Service

Tags: image, rest, security, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a microservice system. One of microservices is used for image management. I gonna create an endpoint that will provide an image through GET-request. But the service isn't internal so I have to protect this endpoint to make it accessible only for my apps. I thought about some tokens and so on but may be there is any best practices? 
Thanks!

Comment: You should always protect your apis with some kind of auth. Read this:          https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/why-use-access-tokens-to-secure-apis

Comment: If you would not expose the image service for other users, you could check the request ip in your image service for simple way to protect the service. Otherwise, you will need to implement auth features.